# JavaFX in Scala too late repaint

Tags: scala, user-interface, javafx

I have a Scala Program with JavaFX GUI. When I fire a button, I disable my button and change a label text before calling a function that takes several tens of seconds to execute (RobotWebCore.runSearch()). The problem is that the GUI do not display the changes I bring to it before calling my function (but only after) :/

Here my code:

```
class GuiController extends Initializable {

  @FXML
  var GUI : VBox = null;

    @FXML
    var RQ_TEXT_FIELD : TextField = null;

    @FXML 
    var SEARCH_BUTTON : Button = null;

    @FXML
    var STATE_LABEL : Label = null;

    override def initialize(location : URL, resources : ResourceBundle ) = {
      Printer.activeGui = true;
      GuiController.instance = this;
        SEARCH_BUTTON.setOnMousePressed(e => runSearch());
    }

  def setStateMessage(message: String) = STATE_LABEL.setText(message);

  private def runSearch() = {
    val p = ExpressionParser.LocalParser.parse(RQ_TEXT_FIELD.getText);
    if (p.successful) {
      GUI.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
      SEARCH_BUTTON.setDisable(true);
      setStateMessage("Recherche en cours");
      RobotWebCore.runSearch(p.get);
      SEARCH_BUTTON.setDisable(false);
      GUI.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    } else {
      setStateMessage("Requête invalide ! Exemple : (chat and chat) or perroquet");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaFX doesn't render until [a "pulse"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) occurs. And you appear to be executing a long-running task on the _JavaFX Application Thread_ (i.e. the call to `RobotWebCore.runSearch`), which means the `runSearch` method doesn't return and the pulse can't occur (and the GUI is likely frozen). Use a separate thread to run the search and communicate back to the FX thread—see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, I was on the same idea, but the execution time of the `RobotWebCore.runSearch` increases a lot in passing on a second Thread (by instantiate Thread object). This difference in execution time is normal?

Comment: You mention the `RobotWebCore.runSearch` method runs for "several for tens of seconds". With that long of a running task the cost of starting a new `Thread` should be barely noticeable. It also shouldn't matter what thread is executing the code (assuming it's isolated to one thread or thread-safe). You could try using an `ExecutorService` to reuse threads (also look into `javafx.concurrent.Service`). Try profiling your code to see where the performance degradation takes place.

Comment: I just tried with Task JavaFX, and it works perfectly without much loss of execution time! Thanks very much!